# How to add an emoji to comment in IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1?

Tags: intellij-idea

When I copy emoji and paste it to my new IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1 to the comment line - it just becomes grey.
Here's a link with emoji http://getemoji.com/ one of them didn't work

Comment: Aren't all comments gray in IntelliJ?

Comment: @Rumid I suppose, according to this screen from official notes https://d3nmt5vlzunoa1.cloudfront.net/idea/files/2016/12/idea_2017_1_emoji.png 
it shouldn't be grey

Comment: What OS do you have?

Comment: @Rumid I am using Windows 10 64-bit

Comment: From the same page


"On Mac OS X emoji characters are rendered as colored images. On Windows and Linux emoji are rendered as monochrome characters."


Case solved.

Comment: Use `ctrl+alt+;` on Linux. (just thought to add the comment since I found the answer elsewhere.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1 emoji characters are rendered as colored images only on Mac OS X.

On Windows and Linux emoji are rendered as monochrome characters.

Comment: Whyyyyy does it have to be like this? I want my nice colorful emoticons in my comments... 

Answer (score 20):

Sorry, this might be coming late but I think it could be helpful for future users.

On **Windows**, it is the <kbd>Win</kbd>+

On **Mac** it is <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>